# print hash within array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, hash

if I have an array with hashes inside, how do I print only the hash keyvalue pairs ?

```
  complex_array= [ 1,2, 3, "string", 
               {"app1"=>"123 happy street",
                "app2"=>"daf 3 street", 
                "app3"=>"random street"}, "random", {"another"=>"hash"}
               ]
```

I'm trying to do:

```
complex_array.select{|x|
 puts x["app1"];
 }
```

that doesn't work, because with arrays you need an index parameter (no conversion of string to integer error)

So how do I only print the values of the hash(s) without specifying the index of the hash within the array first, or is that the only way ?

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through each element of the array and determine if that class of the element is a hash. If so, then puts the key value pairs of that hash element. The second looping is necessary in case there are multiple key value pairs.

```
 complex_array.each do |element|
   if element.class == Hash
     element.each do |key, value|
       puts "key: #{key}, value: #{value}"
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: Your `if` is better than my `select`.

Comment: thanks !
i was just curious as to if there was a more elegant solution in ruby (without having to do a check to see if the element is a hash first) i guess not?

Answer (score 1):

Just select the elements that are hashes, then for each hash, print the key-value pairs:

```
complex_array.select { |e| e.is_a? Hash }
             .each { |h| h.each { |k,v| puts "#{k}=>#{v}" } }
  # app1=>123 happy street
  # app2=>daf 3 street
  # app3=>random street
  # another=>hash
```